# What kind of string to use for the ice fishing experiment for kids?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, water, home-experiment, melting-point

[Classic ice fishing experiment for kids.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvi26XKc_sc)

I used [nylon](http://www.ebay.com/itm/W6-0-5mm-Diameter-Freshwater-Nylon-Fishing-Line-Thread-/182220489624) because I saw it in a stationery, and apparently that doesn't work [because I guess it's too slippery](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zaqn1ElFSW0J:www.umanitoba.ca/outreach/crystal/Grade%25205/Cluster%25202/5-2-05%2520-%2520Ice%2520Fishing%2520-%2520Demonstration%2520and%2520Investigation.doc%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=hk). I tried thread from my mom's sewing kit, but that doesn't work either.

I'm not sure I can find [yarn or kite string](http://www.sciencefun.org/kidszone/experiments/ice-fishing/) in the stationery or nearby so please suggest alternatives expected to be found in the average household, supermarket, grocery store or convenience store.

Also how long should we wait? The above video takes only 10 seconds while this video takes about 2 minutes (off screen). What factors influence waiting time? Amount of salt? Type of string?

Comment: I've had good results using sewing kit string or thin twine.

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I'm voting to close it as off-topic because it has essentially nothing to do with chemistry.

Comment: @hBy2Py OP wants to know about the factors influencing waiting time. Surely that's 'on-topic'?

Comment: @paracresol I did not take the time to visit the link provided at the start of OP's question ("ice fishing experiment" gives no indication that chemistry is involved, to my mind). Perhaps the information there makes it more of a chemistry question? If so, OP should edit the question to include details of the experiment, and I will gladly retract my close vote.

Comment: "Ice fishing" is trying to melt a string into a piece of ice using salt. The ice re-freezes, allow you to pull the ice up with the string. I aggre that "ice fishing" is a very poor description though. Should be fixed to keep open.

Comment: @hBy2Py why is having the details in question so important that you 'will' and not 'might' retract? How about we just pretend the details are there? I think not having details makes post less wordy. Why use links in the first place instead of just copying entire webpages? See [office fire](http://mathandmultimedia.com/2015/01/25/5-math-jokes-engineer-physicist-mathematician/)

Comment: @BCLC Because without them there is no obvious relevance to chemistry. In my experience, the term "ice fishing" refers most commonly to 'cutting a hole in a frozen-over lake, and catching fish through it.' With an explanation present, indicating that 'ice fishing' is used in the sense of 'exploiting the freezing point depression induced by salt to penetrate a string into a piece of ice,' the relevance is clear and straightforward. There are still elements to the question that are of uncertain relevance, but they are minor enough for me to retract the close vote.

Comment: @hBy2Py okay so that's your experience. Is that necessarily most people's experience? [False consensus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_consensus_effect) ? PS Please see edit of previous comment

Comment: @BCLC This is from the 'answering' section of the Help Center, but see the "Provide context for links" blurb [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). What happens if that YouTube video gets taken down for copyright violations? Your question will then have lost crucial context. Thus, the importance of at least summarizing what you want the reader to get out of the content at the link.

Comment: @BCLC "*okay so that's your experience. Is that necessarily most people's experience?*" Clearly not, since as of this comment only one other person has voted to close. :-)  My close vote and above comments are not meant to tell others what to think; they are to declare what I think. If an insufficient number of people also vote to close within the next couple of days, my close vote will expire, the question will stay open, and I'll be perfectly content with it. That's the SE model for making decisions like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50499/discussion-between-hby2py-and-bclc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This resource](http://www3.rmsc.org/museum/kidsclub/experiments/fishing/fishing.htm) has an explaination of the behavior, which relies on the salt-dissolved water wicking into the string. This would mean that you need a type of string which will absorb water. It's surprising to me that your nylon string doesn't work (as long as it's thick/low-density enough to absorb water, probably unlike fishing line), is it possible it has a hydrophobic coating?

I would recommend any cotton-based string or twine. Cooking twine and sewing thread is often cotton, if you have access to that. I've had no problems with these.

Edit: I just thought, that you might want to try this not in a cup of water first (like in the link above). You might potentially run into not-string-related problems if your water isn't cold enough, or if your ice gets too submerged when you put the salt on it. It's possible your nylon string is fine.

Comment: Hmm. Do you wait long enough for the salt to melt the water on the top of the ice-cube?

Comment: idk. I think so? I thijk i resd 10 seconds. I waited 30. I'll try again later

Comment: I'm sure you've already thought of this too, then, but my other idea on timing is that you also want to be sure to wait long enough that the water (with salt wicked away) freezes between the string and the ice.

Comment: I put ice in a bowl or plate and then put salt over ice and then lightly tapped salt over ice with back of spoon. Then it worked. Any idea why the tapping works? Thanks once again. Merry Christmas, Happy Holidays, and Happy New Year!